# Trouble setting up Rails, sqLite 3 won't install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, command-line, sqlite

Here's what happens when I try installing it.

```
C:\Users\XXXX>gem install sqlite3
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32
unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/sqlite3/1.8/sqlite3_na
tive.so, skipping
unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/sqlite3/1.9/sqlite3_na
tive.so, skipping
1 gem installed
```

The command I'm trying to do with is just `gem install sqlite3` which produces this:

```
C:\Users\XXXX>gem install sqlite3
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32
Parsing documentation for sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32
unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/sqlite3/1.8/sqlite3_na
tive.so, skipping
unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/sqlite3/1.9/sqlite3_na
tive.so, skipping
1 gem installed
```

This is extremely frustrating - I am new to Rails and know very little about command line and Gem installer or databases even. Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Existing pre-compiled gems are not Ruby 2.0 compatible

Ruby 2.0 introduces ABI breakage which means compiled C extensions with previous 
1.9.3 will work with Ruby 2.0.

DO NOT install Ruby 2.0 on top of existing Ruby 1.9.3, or try to use compiled 
extensions with it.

You will be required to force compilation of those gems:

```
gem install <name> --platform=ruby
```

This will require you have the extra dependencies required for that gem to 
compile. Look at the gem documentation for the requirements.

pls visit https://github.com/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/issues/84 for detailed explaination